# Images and styling not rendered correctly on page refresh

Tags: theming, caching, media

The problem is that images and some styles are not correctly rendered when I hit `Cmd+R` and doing a refresh, but it is working fine on a reload.

So my question is not what the difference between a reload and a refresh is, as that would be off topic, but I want to know what Drupal specific reasons could cause this.

As I have read I think that it maybe could be some files directory permissions, but it does'nt seems to be that.

Anyone who ran into this before?

Comment: Are you doing something like a background url output as a twig variable? I just found that it does `&amp;` instead of `&` in URLs which returns a 403 for image style URLs until the image style is generated. To fix that I used `|raw` on my custom variable.

Comment: No I am rendering the images like the fields {{ content.image_field }}